# Mallongigoj Specialaj de Vortaro.net

Tags: dictionaries

Mi trovas multajn mallongigojn en Vortaro.net (ekz *suf[ikso]*, *k[aj]*, ktp), sed ne komprenas iuj el tiuj, kaj ne povas trovi liston de ĉiuj mallongigoj uzataj en ĝi. Ĉu iu povas helpi min pri tio bonvole?

Mi ne serĉas liston de kutimaj Esperantaj mallongigoj. Mi bezonas nur tiujn kiuj estas specialaj de Vortaro.net.

---

In Vortaro.net, I encounter many abbreviations (e.g., *suf[ikso]*, *k[aj]*, etc.), but I don't understand some of them and can't find a list of all abbreviations used in it. Can someone help me about that, please?

I'm not looking for a list of common Esperanto abbreviations. I need only those which are specific to Vortaro.net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) kaj PIV (kiu estas la fonto de [Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/)) estas du forkoj de la sama originala verko ([la Plena Vortaro de Esperanto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plena_Vortaro_de_Esperanto)), do mi supozas ke ili uzas la samajn mallongigojn. La Reta Vortaro havas [liston de mallongigoj](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/mallongigoj.html) kiun mi kopias ĉi tie:

---

The [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) and PIV (which is the source of [Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/)) are derived from the same original work (the [Plena Vortaro de Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plena_Vortaro_de_Esperanto)), so I suppose that they use the same abbreviations. The Reta Vortaro has a [list of abbreviations](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/mallongigoj.html) which I'm copying here:

> *****
>       fundamenta
>   **1**
>       1a oficiala aldono
>   **2**
>       2a oficiala aldono
>   **3**
>       3a oficiala aldono
>   **4**
>       4a oficiala aldono
>   **5**
>       5a oficiala aldono
>   **6**
>       6a oficiala aldono
>   **7**
>       7a oficiala aldono
>   **8**
>       8a oficiala aldono
>   **9**
>       9a oficiala aldono
>   **abs.**
>       absolute, senkomplemente
>   **adj.**
>       adjektivo
>   **adv.**
>       adverbo
>   **a.K.**
>       antaŭ Kristo
>   **akuz.**
>       akuzativo
>   **anst.**
>       anstataŭ
>   **ark.**
>       arkaismo
>   **B**
>       Bein
>   **C**
>       Christaller
>   **ĉap.**
>       ĉapitro
>   **D**
>       Millidge
>   **ekz.**
>       ekzemple
>   **E-o**
>       Esperanto
>   **F**
>       Fulcher k Long
>   **f**
>       figure, metafore
>   **fam.**
>       familio
>   **G**
>       Grabowski
>   **G.**
>       genro
>   **i.a.**
>       interalia
>   **inf.**
>       infinitivo
>   **interj.**
>       interjekcio
>   **jc**
>       jarcento
>   **K**
>       Krestomatio
>   **k. a.**
>       kaj aliaj
>   **kc**
>       kaj ceteraj
>   **ks**
>       kaj similaj
>   **ktp**
>       kaj tiel plu
>   **konj.**
>       konjunkcio
>   **Kp**
>       Komparu
>   **LI**
>       Lingvo Internacia
>   **LK**
>       Lingva Komitato
>   **N**
>       Bennemann
>   **ntr**
>       netransitiva
>   **p.**
>       paĝo(j)
>   **pp**
>       parolante pri
>   **part.**
>       participo
>   **pref.**
>       prefikso
>   **prep.**
>       prepozicio
>   **pron.**
>       pronomo
>   **prop.**
>       propozicio
>   **R**
>       Rollet de l'Isle
>   **resp.**
>       respektive
>   **Rim.**
>       Rimarko
>   **simb.**
>       simbolo
>   **sk**
>       subkomprenu
>   **subst.**
>       substantivo
>   **suf.**
>       sufikso
>   **t.e.**
>       tio estas
>   **tr**
>       transitiva
>   **trad.**
>       tradukis
>   **veg.**
>       vegetaĵo
>   **Vd**
>       Vidu
>   **vol.**
>       volumo
>   **x**
>       transitiva kaj netransitiva
>   **Y**
>       diversaj aliaj vortaristoj
>   **Z**
>       Zamenhof