# Symbol key for PIV online?

Tags: books, akademia-vortaro

The [*PIV* online](http://vortaro.net) uses many symbols that can *sometimes* be deduced—but not always.

For instance, if you look up [*mortiĝi*](http://vortaro.net/#morti%C4%9Di), you get:

[image: screenshot of PIV]

You can hover over “evi” to discover it means *evitinda* (avoidable), and the blue-on-green superscript “Z” means the quote is from Zamenhof, but what does the asterisk mean? (In linguistics, a prefix asterisk means “wrong”, and that might make sense here since *mortiĝi* is “avoidable”.)

Then a symbol like **☞** obviously means “see also”…. The cross in the entry for *mortinda* is telling you that “mortal sin” is a Catholic usage. Or… maybe it means a Christian usage—or maybe, just “religious”? How can one know?

Other symbols such as **⚥** are, like the cross, understandable in context, but for a reference work, it would be nice to know their “official” meanings.

Maybe I’m just missing something obvious, but I can’t find a “key” or any other “front matter”, and searching for symbols doesn’t produce anything:
[image: A search for ⚥ giving: “Eraro: Bedaŭrinde la serĉo ne estis sukcesa!“]

Is there a “cheat sheet” somewhere? I imagine a printed *PIV* would have this, but I don’t have one handy.

> *(Note: an earlier version of this question said I also would like a key to abbreviations in the PIV, but that, it was suggested, made this question a duplicate of another question. Although that answer is in Spanish, so I’m not quite certain it’s a* real *duplicate in the useful sense, it’s not my place to say—so I’ve removed references to abbreviations. There were comments and answers added that only addressed that part of the question, so you may want to take that into account in reading seemingly-unresponsive comments/answers.)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mallongigoj Specialaj de Vortaro.net](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/mallongigoj-specialaj-de-vortaro-net)

Comment: Question [Mallongigoj Specialaj de Vortaro.net](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/3619/1576) and the [accepted answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/3620/1576) there are of course in Esperanto, not in Spanish. :-) But due to the importance of that question and answer, maybe adding an English translation would indeed be prudent. The question here as-is now after editing (i.e., without referring to abbreviations, but only to symbols) is IMHO indeed **no** duplicate of [Mallongigoj Specialaj de Vortaro.net](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/3619/1576).

Comment: I've edited question [Mallongigoj Specialaj de Vortaro.net](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/3619/1576) and its currently [accepted answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/3620/1576) to include English translations. :-)

Comment: @das-g thank you—but as noted above, in order to avoid this question being closed as a duplicate, it’s now strictly about the symbols and not the abbreviations. I do appreciate the effort though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the asterisk you'll get the message "Fundamenta", to indicate that the word *mortiĝi* appears in the *Universala Vortaro* of the *Fundamento de Esperanto*. As long as you can hover over those symbols and abbreviations everything is fine. But wait! Did you notice the k-letter in *la domo forbrulis **k** la juna pasero mortiĝis*? It is an abbreviation for *kaj*. That particular one is easy to guess. But there are a bunch of others, which are less intuitive and, even worse, aren't hoverable. Some examples: *Sp.* in *[figbirdo](http://vortaro.net/#figbirdo)* (for *Specio*). How about: g., sk, jc, pp., and so forth.

You'll find some lists of abbreviations here and there. Reta Vortaro has one [here](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/mallongigoj.html). Another one, more comprehensive and downloadable as PDF, is [this one](https://vdocuments.site/download/abreviaciones-del-esperanto).

---

### UPDATE

The new PIV 2020 includes a **[Listo de la mallongigoj kaj simboloj uzataj en la vortaro](https://bertilow.com/vortaro.net/mallongigoj_simboloj.html)**. According to [Bertilo](https://bertilow.com/bertiloblogo/?p=340):

> PIV 2020 loĝas nun provizore ĉe la adreso [bertilow.com/vortaro.net/](https://bertilow.com/vortaro.net/).
> Sed iam poste ĝi estos ĉe [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net), kie nun troviĝas PIV 2005.

Comment: I can't download the PDF. The page asks me to wait 60 s and when the time is finally up and the download button gets enabled, I press it and get a message saying expiration error.

Comment: @Juha Metsäkallas: Strange! Mi ĵus provis kaj elŝutis la dosieron senprobleme. Mi alŝutis ĝin al [WeTransfer](https://we.tl/t-dw024k6N6s) kaj esperas ke ĝi funkcios por vi kaj aliaj.

Comment: Elŝutado el WeTransfer funkcias por mi. Dankon!

Comment: The symbols are much more confusing to me, @Vidamuzo — I can look up the abbreviations with Google even if they aren’t in PIV themselves (and many are). As for hovering, I have a physical disability and not all the devices I use support hovering—nor do mobile browsers for anyone.

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn’t clear from my last comment, @Vidamuzo, I’ll accept your answer if you can provide a key to the symbols. But I honestly haven’t been able to assign any rhyme or reason to some of them that are recurring, such as ⚥ — yes, these definitions have _something_ to do with sex or gender, but I could figure that out from the definition; it isn’t like ⚓, where it’s obvious that it means _«ŝipa aŭ mararmea»_.

Comment: For instance, the symbol  (which in the font on Stack Exchange turns into a color emoji of two heads, but on PIV, for instance at _[salo](http://vortaro.net/#salo)_, is shown as a handshake) I can see by opening the HTML source that the hovertext is “Komuna senca” — but that means “the most common dictionary sense”, not “common sense” in its overloaded English meaning (which is _komuna prudento_).

Comment: @Trey: Try as I might, I wasn't able to find a key to the symbols. I guess the publishers of vortaro.net may help you via their [contact form](http://vortaro.net/kontakti). I suggest you leave the question open until an acceptable answer is given (even by yourself). Meanwhile, here you'll find [a few explanations](http://www.satesperanto.org/IMG/pdf/prelegbratis.pdf) about those symbols (page 8).

Comment: @Trey: There are various handicaps (e.g., tremor or blindness) that keep users from normally using any pointing device (such as a mouse or trackpad). I therefore assume there must be means for those users (maybe built-in to browsers, maybe provided by add-ons, screen readers or other assisting software) to access hover texts on websites. Maybe you can research what means exist and use one of those. As a last resort (because not particularly ergonomic) you can always view the HTML source code of a vortaro.net web page to reveal hover texts. They'll usually be in the `title` attribute.

Comment: @das-g I have put quite a bit of effort in the past into finding ways to see hover-text on Android and/or iOS/iPadOS, and except for getting the raw source and searching (which itself is a bit of a pain since mobile browsers usually lack “view source”) I haven’t found any such solutions. Many web sites that have mobile versions (e.g., [xkcd](https://m.xkcd.com)) explicitly have alternate interfaces for hovertext (in xkcd’s case if you click the link, an “alt-text” link that reveals the hover-text).

Comment: @das-g That said, perhaps someone maintaining vortaro.net saw this post—because on mobile browsers, the symbols are now directly clickable to toggle the hover-text! It definitely was not true before, for me at least....

Comment: @Trey: I updated my answer providing new information about your question.

Comment: @Vidamuzo Thanks! Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I copied four pages (mallongigoj, simboloj, signoj) from PIV 2002. You can find the pdf-file here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qVDkKqsC2GajD3ZO2FM0LMXDOl2Bq0Um

I can't guarantee the file will remain there indefinitely, so feel free to copy it into a more appropriate place. Don't forget to post the new link here.

The mysterious symbols are a nuisance in PIV – legacy of French lexicography I suppose. Abbreviations are a bit less mysterious, but even they should be avoided in a web dictionary.

One symbol you mention is the asterisk. It certainly doesn't mean the word is ungrammatical (the usual meaning in linguistics). Quite the contrary: the words preceded by an asterisk are core elements of Esperanto vocabulary, defined in the *Fundamento de Esperanto*.

Comment: Thank you! I’d accept this answer if it weren’t for the unofficial and possibly transient nature of your PDF. Perhaps I’ll make a text version (if I convert to Unicode/emoji symbols and don’t copy wholesale from the source, it probably would constitute fair use). Perfect — and thanks for the correction on the asterisk.

Comment: — if I do make that list of ~65 symbols, would you like me to provide them to you to add to your answer, or shall I answer it myself? This will probably take a couple days as some of the characters aren’t in Unicode, so were adapted to something else for Vortaro and I’ll have to figure out what those are. (I’m _very_ amused to see that the plain white box I’d assumed indicated a symbol or emoji my fonts don’t have is simply, for some reason, the symbol they chose for the book and maintained online, for “physics”.)

Comment: Actually, it may be quite a bit harder than it seems. Because they chose the most representative Unicode glyphs, even when they didn’t look like the 2002 printing—but in order to preserve these looks, they use a special webfont. So, for instance, ☸, which is the wheel of Dharma symbol, is used for _Budhismo_ — but the PIV webfont preserves it as a meditating silhouette. No way to use the webfont here on Stack Exchange (or, for that matter, on any site I could post content to). So I’ll have to do lots of screenshot/imagemanip work, sigh.

Comment: Harri, thanks for this—it was extremely helpful until @Vidamuzo reported on the new 2020 addition above.